# Obtener el número de caracteres en común entre dos cadenas de texto en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones, bucles, programación-funcional

Intento resolver, usando sólo elementos básicos de funciones, así como `condicionales` y `loops`, lo siguiente: Obtener, entre dos cadenas de texto, el número total de letras que tienen en común, considerando que cada letra en común cuenta sólo como una. Es decir, si tengo "perro" y "ropa", el resultado debería ser 3. (p, r, o).

Pensando en el problema, intuyo que debe abordarse utilizando un doble `for` y luego comparando si cada elemento de la cadena A es igual a cada elemento de la cadena B, sumamos la cantidad de elementos iguales y tenemos el resultado.

Así, lo primero que se me ocurrió fue esto:

```
def stringc(s1, s2):
    count=0
    for s in s1:
        for t in s2:
            if s==t:
                count+=1
                return count


stringc("perro", "ropa")

##Salida
1
```

Como puede apreciarse, está alejado de lo que busco. Ahora bien, utilizando `print` en lugar de `return` (aunque `return` es lo que debe emplearse), obtengo una salida un poco más cercana a lo que busco, aunque se imprime una lista de números del 1 al 4. En principio, el número acumulado para el ejemplo debería ser 3, y sólo me interesa obtener dicho número.

```
def stringc(s1, s2):
    count=0
    for s in s1:
        for t in s2:
            if s==t:
                count+=1
                print(count)

##Las siguientes son cadenas de prueba:

stringc("perro", "ropa")

##Salida:

1
2
3
4
```

Aunque creo que mi intuición es correcta, agradezco me hagan saber mis errores de lógica y de programación. (Ojo: No deben usarse ni `append` ni otros métodos. Digamos que lo interesante del problema es lograr lo deseado con las herramientas más rudimentarias de `Python`)

Comment: Saca el print del bucle más anidado, porque le estás utilizando siempre. Ponlo fuera de los for, con el return te pasa lo mismo. Hace la primera comparación pone count a 1 y se sale con el return.

Comment: Puedes usar diccionarios? Si puedes con ello reducirías mucho y luego ya la comparación. En tu solución vas a tener un problema con la doble r, ya que te la contará como 2

Comment: @lDanny7:  No, en realidad debe resolverse sólo con cosas muy muy básicas. Los diccionarios vienen después dentro del texto que leo para aprender algo de Python, así que, en teoría, no puede usarse.

Comment: @Raulitus: Lo que comentas resuelve uno de los problemas (tener un sólo número en lugar de una secuencia) pero no el otro (letras repetidas). Gracias por hacerme notar ese error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te comentaba lo mejor es usar diccionario, pero como me dijiste que no se podía usar se puede crear una función para reducir el string. La función reducirString elimina los caracteres repetidos y luego si se puede aplicar lo que ya tenias.

```
def reducirString(texto):
    textoReducido = ""
    for letra in texto:
        if letra not in textoReducido:
            textoReducido += letra

    return textoReducido

def stringc(s1, s2):
    count=0
    s1 = reducirString(s1)
    s3 = reducirString(s2)
    for s in s1:
        for t in s2:
            if s==t:
                count+=1

    return count
```

Espero que te funcione.

Comment: Excelente solución. Aprecio mucho tu tiempo :)

Answer (score 2):

Respondiendo por partes

### Error de lógica en tu código

Dejando de lado que no estás considerando aún el tema de las letras repetidas, el principal error es poner el `return` dentro del bucle.

Cuando una función alcanza una instrucción `return count`, abandona su ejecución y retorna el valor que tenga la variable `count` *en ese momento*. Ya que justo acababas de incrementarla, valdrá 1.

Obviamente la solución es esperar a que el bucle termine, y *después* retornar el valor de la variable, que ya será 4.

Por otro lado, ya que estás aprendiendo, es importante que desde el principio te acostumbres a poner buenos nombres para las funciones y los parámetros, de modo que sean autoexplicativos. De lo contrario leer el código requiere más esfuerzo. Otros programadores (y tu *yo futuro*) te lo agradecerán.

Con estas ideas reescribo así tu código:

```
def contar_letras_en_comun(cadena1, cadena2):
    count=0
    for letra1 in cadena1:
        for letra2 in cadena2:
            if letra1==:
                count+=1
    return count
```

### No usar cosas "avanzadas"

Dejando todavía de lado el tema de la repetición de letras, una mejora que inmediatamente se me ocurre al ver el código anterior es eliminar el bucle interno haciendo uso de la expresión python `subcadena in cadena` que te devuelve `True` si la `subcadena` aparece dentro de la `cadena`. No sé si consideras esta expresión python "avanzado", pero yo lo consideraría bastante básico.

Haciendo uso de esto:

```
def contar_letras_en_comun(cadena1, cadena2):
    count=0
    for letra in cadena1:
        if letra in cadena2:
            count+=1
    return count
```

No solo deja el código más corto, sino que también será más rápida su ejecución, pues los bucles python deben ser interpretados instrucción a instrucción, mientras que la operación `in`, aunque al final para calcularla python usará también bucles, esos bucles no son instrucciones python, sino instrucciones máquina dentro del propio intérprete, que fue programado en C, y por tanto más rápidas.

Como bonus, bajo mi punto de vista queda más legible.

### Eliminar letras duplicadas

Para evitar contar una letra dos veces no queda más remedio que llevar un registro de qué letras has contado ya. Una forma típica sería usar un diccionario, pero tal vez consideres esto "avanzado", así que lo intentaremos de otra forma.

Otra forma sería crear una lista para ir metiendo en ella las letras que ya hemos visto, y sólo contamos las letras nuevas que no estuvieran ya en esa otra lista. Por desgracia eso implica que la lista debe comenzar vacía e ir creciendo. En el enunciado explícitamente decías que no se podía usar `.append()`, con lo que esta solución también queda fuera.

De hecho, con unas restricciones tan exigentes (ausencia de estructuras de datos dinámicas, es decir, que puedan ir aumentando su tamaño), es casi imposible resolver el problema, salvo que haga trampa.

La trampa que voy a hacer es tener una cadena auxiliar en la cual ir metiendo las letras que ya hemos visto. Para añadir una letra nueva haré: `auxiliar = auxiliar + letra`, lo cual en el fondo es una forma tramposa de hacer un `append()`. Bueno, en rigor no, porque `append()` modifica la lista, mientras que la concatenación de cadenas crea una cadena nueva (y la reasigna a la misma variable) cada vez. Pero el resultado es el mismo.

Con esta idea quedará así:

```
def contar_letras_en_comun(cadena1, cadena2):
    letras_ya_vistas = ""
    count=0
    for letra in cadena1:
        if (letra not in letras_ya_vistas) and (letra in cadena2):
           count+=1
        letras_ya_vistas += letra
    return count
```

### Solución pythónica

Aunque esto se sale de lo que preguntabas, no puedo dejar de escribir también cuál sería la forma más "pythónica" de hacerlo. Este adjetivo (pythónico) se usa para referirse a características propias del lenguaje (no necesariamente avanzadas, sino típicas de python e inexistentes en otros lenguajes como C) que permiten escribir un código mucho más elegante, fácil de leer y más eficiente a la hora de ejecutarse.

En este caso, el quiz de la cuestión está en usar conjuntos. El tipo de datos conjunto automáticamente resuelve el problema de las repeticiones (pues en un conjunto cada elemento se guarda una sola vez) y además tiene la operación de intersección, que sirve para encontrar las letras comunes.

La solución sería ahora mucho más simple, y no tendría bucles:

```
def contar_letras_en_comun(cadena1, cadena2):
    letras_en_cadena1 = set(cadena1)
    letras_en_cadena2 = set(cadena2)
    letras_en_comun = letras_en_cadena1.intersection(letras_en_cadena2)
    return (len(letras_en_comun))
```

Naturalmente esto podría considerarse "avanzado" y se sale del objetivo de tu pregunta, pero es una pena no aprovechar lo que el lenguaje te da.

Comment: Lo hago así porque aunque conozco algunos temas intermedios-avanzados en Python, trato de repasar desde cero ya que estoy un poco "oxidado". Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta.